OTVinta Blender code doesn't work in B42
Here's the code:
Source: (Using their Python Script Generator)
Tutorial: https://otvinta.com/tutorial21.html
Script Generator: https://otvinta.com/matrix.html
Spinning Hypocycloid-based Spiral: Code Generated

import bpy
from math import *
import math
def createMeshFromData(name, origin, verts, edges, faces):
# Create mesh and object
me = bpy.data.meshes.new(name+'Mesh')
ob = bpy.data.objects.new(name, me)
ob.location = origin
ob.show_name = False
# Link object to scene and make active
if bpy.app.version_string[0:3] < "2.8":
scn = bpy.context.scene
scn.objects.link(ob)
scn.objects.active = ob
ob.select = True
else:
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(ob)
ob.select_set(True)
# Create mesh from given verts, faces.
me.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)
# smooth shade
values = [True] * len(me.polygons)
me.polygons.foreach_set("use_smooth", values)

# Update mesh with new data
me.update()

u = 32
v = 128
x = lambda u, v: 1
y = lambda u, v: 0
z = lambda u, v: 0
verts = [ [x(i/u, j/v), y(i/u, j/v), z(i/u, j/v)] for j in range(v+1) for i in range(u+1) ]
faces = [ [(u+1)*j+i, (u+1)*j+i+1, (u+1)*j+i+u+2, (u+1)*j+i+u+1] for j in range(v) for i in range(u)]
createMeshFromData('Surface3D', [0, 0, 0], verts, [], faces)


Here's the video explaining it:
https://youtu.be/W4ViqzbF96Q
Here's the link to the blend file from this video:
https://otvinta.com/images/SplitFlapFinalResult.zip
